# Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync Dialog does not close

Tags: typescript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

When pressing the close button *(x)* of the Dialog (displayed in an iframe) the displayed iframe is removed, but the panel including the close button and heading still remains. I found following error in the logs, but I'm not sure if it is related `TypeError: o.get_contextActivationManager is not a function` occurred in `owa.clientnext.extensibility.js:7:1898`.

The Exchange server version is *15.1 ‎(Build 1034.26)‎*.
The Probelm occured in

- Firefox *55.0.3 (32-Bit)*
- Chrome *61.0.3163.100 (Offizieller Build) (64-Bit)*
- IE *11.0.9600.18792*

I use following function to create the dialog:

```ts
export async function GetFiles(): Promise<string[]> {

    return new Promise<string[]>((resolve, reject) => {

        Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(window.location.origin +
            '/exchangeAddIn/UploadDialog/index.html',
            {
                height: 50,
                width: 50,
                displayInIframe: true
            },
            (asyncResult: Office.AsyncResult) => {
                if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                    Logger.error('Faild Dialog %o', asyncResult);
                    reject();
                }
                else {
                    let dialogHandler = asyncResult.value as Office.DialogHandler;

                    dialogHandler.addEventHandler(
                        Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, (args: any) => {
                            dialogHandler.close();
                            if (args.message == null) {
                                resolve();
                            }
                            let array = JSON.parse(args.message) as string[];
                            resolve(array);
                        });

                    dialogHandler.addEventHandler(
                        Office.EventType.DialogEventReceived, (arg: any) => {
                            reject();
                        });
                }
            });
    });

}
```

Comment: In your `DialogEventReceived`, is `arg.error` being returned as `12006` when this occurs?

Comment: Also, is your GetFiles function called from a task pane or from a command in a ribbon button or menu item?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT yes the error code is 12006.

Comment: @RickKirkham The function is called from a task pane.

Comment: We have tried to repro this, but cannot in CU7. If this is fixed in CU7, it is unlikely that the fix would be backported to CU6. Is it possible for you to try and repro this against CU7? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15776.exchange-server-2013-and-2016-build-numbers-with-cumulative-updates.aspx

Comment: Was there a resolution to this? I'm seeing a similar issue in outlook for android version 2.2.91 (244) mainlineProd

Comment: I used another approach, but I didn't had the chance to test CU7 (yet)